# How to call Laravel helper method in Config/Constants.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, helper

I am giving this error
Call to undefined function getDefaultConfigByHost()
In constants.php line 5:

**In helper.php**

```
function getDefaultConfigByHost($developmentValue = null, $testValue = null, 

    $productionValue = null)
    {
        try {
            if (! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
                return null;
            }
            $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            switch ($domain) {
                case 'xxx.gglemd.com':
                    return $developmentValue;
                case '192.168.1.18:8001':
                    return $testValue;
                case 'yyy.service.com':
                    return $productionValue;
                default:
                    return '';
            }
        } catch (Exception  $exception) {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

**In constants.php**

```
<?php
 return [
    'api' => [
        'base'        => env('API_BASE', getDefaultConfigByHost(),
        'sfile_base'  => env('SXFILE_API_BASE', getDefaultConfigByHost('')),
        'private_key' => env('API_REQUEST_PRIVATE_KEY', 'bn-sjaddasdsadsadasdas'),
    ],
];
```

Comment: Did you add your `helper.php` file to `autoload` section in your `composer.json` ?

Comment: I added in ocmposer.json and resolved problem. Thanks..